# How to set up suhosin.ini for unlimited menus

Tags: menus, apache

On my custom menus page, I'm getting a limit (e.g. the users cannot add more menu items). I have done some research and have found that my suhosin settings may not be allowing wordpress enough memory. What is the best way to fix the config so that my menus won't be limited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the answer](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134#comment:12), so I'm posting it to help others out:

In this file (depending on your server setup):

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
```

Change suhosin.ini on the following lines (remove the semicolons if applicable):

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
```

The default 1000 will not work - 5000 seems to work well for my needs (so far!)